# Debezium: MySQL connector, prevent from loading tables without primary keys

Tags: mysql, debezium, cdc

In case we have a table without primary key, the MySQLConnector won't complain, and add the data into Kafka.

However the `JDBCSinkConnector` will then throw a `Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception` due to a `null key and null key schema`.

This is a problem, because if we add the primary key afterwards in the table, the JDBCSinkConnector will remain in an unrecoverable state.

The "easy hack" are:

- deleting everything, adding the PK and re-adding everything -> not good in a production environment with 1000s of tables
- manually skip some messages -> very dependent on devs, very difficult operationally
- set the `tolerance` and move on -> not easy to recover to a consistent state since we constantly have to monitor

A more appropriate way to maintain consistency would be:

- preventing the MySQLConnector to load messages that don't have a PK, so we can stop at the source and solve the problem at the source.

What is the best course of action according to Debezium in a prod environment?

Answer (score 0):

another option would be to rely on `message.key.columns` to set a valid combination of columns as a pseudo primary key in the events so that the JDBC sink connector is capable of operating on the data without the need to establish a primary key on the source table.

Comment: But this cannot work dynamicly for every table inside a database a you need to define for each table an alternative or for only those tables without primary key